# What does putting [ngClass]="class"and [ngStyle]="style" do to an element when creating a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and while I was studying some angular code online (how to make a component), I stumbled upon this :

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-okra-button',
  template: `<button [ngClass]="class" [ngStyle]="style" (click)="pay()">Init Okra</button>`,
})
```

but I do not understand the use of `[ngClass]="class" [ngStyle]="style"` used in the button template. What does it do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) attribute allows a string (list of classes as space-delimited string), array of strings (list of classes) or object (with the keys as the classes and the values as whether the classes should be applied) to be specified.

However, the [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) attribute only allows an object (with the keys as the style names with an optional `.<unit>` prefix and the values which is an expression to be evaluated) to be specified.

For example:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'my-class': hasMyClass, 'another-class': true}"
    [ngStyle]="{'display': isBlockDisplay ? 'block' : 'none', 'color': 'red'}">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div [ngClass]="'my-class second-class'">
  <!-- Even more content here -->
</div>
<div [ngClass]="['my-class, 'another-second-class']">
  <!-- Wow, that's a lot of content! -->
</div>
<div [ngStyle]="{'max-width.em': maxWidthNumber}">
  <p>Hello! This should be in a div with a max-width.</p>
</div>
```

```js
export class MyComponent {
  isBlockDisplay = true;
  hasMyClass = false;
  maxWidthNumber = 2;
}
```

The expected rendered HTML should be as follows:

```html
<div class="another-class" style="display: block; color: red">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
<div class="my-class second-class">
  <!-- Even more content here -->
</div>
<div class="my-class another-second-class">
  <!-- Wow, that's a lot of content! -->
</div>
<div style="max-width: 2em">
  <p>Hello! This should be in a div with a max-width.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`[ngClass]="class"` is used to set css classes to the button tag, it allows you to add it statically or based on conditions.

`[ngStyle]="style"` is used to set css styles to the button tag, it allows you to add it statically or based on conditions.

for more details [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Data Binding**. By wrapping a property or directive between brackets (`[]`) you can pass a variable's value from the compoenent to the specified property on the DOM.

If you'd like a simple explanation on how Data binding works, I recommend reading [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/data-binding-angular/). It explains the three types of data binding: **Input, Output and Two Way**.

If you need to know more about [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directives, I suggest to take a look at the official docs.